# Jsoup multiple classes

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have some probably simple problem with Jsoup

Page which i want parse:

```
    <div id="d4861771" class="q post"> 
 <div class="bar"> 
  <div class="right">
    27 kwietnia 2016 08:02 
  </div> 
  <a class="qid click" href="/4861771/">#4861771</a> 
  <a class="click votes rox" rel="nofollow" href="/rox/4861771/">+</a> 
  <span class=" points">614</span> 
  <a class="click votes sux" rel="nofollow" href="/sux/4861771/">-</a> 
  <span class="msg">&nbsp;</span> 
 </div> 
 <div class="quote post-content post-body">
   &lt;gadus&gt; te nowe windowsy są do dupy 
  <br> &lt;gadus&gt; pasjans ma licznik gier 
  <br> &lt;gadus&gt; to tak jakby wbudowane przypominanie o tym jak bardzo marnujesz czas 
 </div> 
</div>
```

and now i need from it date, points and that content in variables but i have no idea how to get them into different variables.

My idea was get all from .text()
then i have:

```
27 kwietnia 2016 08:02 #4861771 + 614 -   <gadus> te nowe windowsy są do dupy <gadus> pasjans ma licznik gier <gadus> to tak jakby wbudowane przypominanie o tym jak bardzo marnujesz czas
```

and just regexp it but i think there is better idea.

My output should look like this:

```
Data: 27 kwietnia 2016 08:02
Points: 614
Content: <gadus> te nowe windowsy są do dupy<...>
```

**I got it!**

```
Elements idd = doc.select("div.q");

for(Element abc : idd){
    System.out.println(abc.getElementsByClass("points").text());
    System.out.println(abc.getElementsByClass("quote").text());
    System.out.println(abc.getElementsByClass("right").text());
}
```

Now i have to delete this post or what?

Comment: It's your own choice whether to delete the question or not. But please don't add the solution to the question itself. If you like to post a working solution, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup......
String data = doc.select(".right").first().text();
String points = doc.select(".points").first().text();
String content = doc.select(".post-content").first().text();
```

You may want to add some checks to make sure that the `select` calls find some elements, otherwise, `text()` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thank you! i found similar idea (edited first post).